# mPDF - Gerar PDF com capa e conteudos

Tags: mpdf

Preciso gerar um PDF com capa, contra-capa e conteúdo.
Estou buscando do banco de dados o nome dos backgrounds e conteúdos.
Até aí, tudo OK.

Fiz o seguinte procedimento:

Primeiro busquei todos os dados que precisava e chamei a view:

```
$this->load->helper('mpdf');
$html_ag = $this->load->view('cliente/geracontrato_pdf_capa', $this->data, true);
```

Na minha view, coloquei:

```
if($dados_modelo_contrato[0]->arquivo_capa){
    $capa = $dados_modelo_contrato[0]->arquivo_capa;
}

<style>
    body { 
        background-image: url(<?php echo base_url("assets/uploads/contratos/uploads/arquivo_capa/".$capa); ?>);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image-resolution:300dpi;background-image-resize:6;
    }
</style>
```

Até aqui, ok, funciona certinho... Gera o PDF com a capa do background.
Agora, preciso acrescentar a contra-capa e o conteúdo abaixo dela, que seria:

```
<capa> imagem (pode ser em background ou src, porém, sem margens)
<contracapa> imagem (pode ser em background ou src, porém, sem margens)
<conteudo> - texto com background normal
```

Como eu faço pra ao invés de usar o body, use então DIVS para imprimir estes conteúdos?